# Pandas - improving memory usage when loading dumped json in column as dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

### Background

I'm using pandas to load a large data set (up to a few million rows) from DB (redshift), some of the columns in the DB are originally jsons saved as strings. After loading the data i use json.loads to convert cells containing dumped json objects to dictionaries. Those objects are around 2.5MB per cell.

### The Problem

While going over large data frames this process can take over 10GB of memory to complete and even crashing on some machines. 
Execution time is also slow but that is a minor problem for me. 
The problem only manifests itself when the cells contain large json objects.

All actions are done in memory and i'd prefer to avoid using HDFS or other in disk solutions as the data frames themselves are more than manageable in memory.

### Failed solution attempts

Using another module to parse the dictionary - 
I've tried using ujson, simplejson and ast.literal_eval instead of the json module but there were no appreciable difference in performance.

Using apply vs using map - tried both and neither seem to improve the memory usage problem.

### The code

The data frame is held in the class as self.df, this is the code handling the transformation:

```
def turnAllJsonColumnsToDict(self):
    """
    Scan the df and turn column to json if it's a string in json format
    """
    print 'Checking columns for needed type conversions'
    for col in self.df.columns:
        if self.check_if_json(self.df[col].iloc[0], col):
            self.loadColumnAsJson(col)

@staticmethod
def check_if_json(col, col_name, should_print=True):
    if isinstance(col, basestring):
        try:
            if col[0] in ('{', '[') and col[-1] in ('}', ']'):
                if should_print:
                    print 'Converting', col_name
                return True
        except IndexError as e:
            if should_print:
                print 'Failed to check ', col_name

@timeIt
def loadColumnAsJson(self, column):
    self.json_load_fail_counter = 0
    self.df[column] = map(self.loadJson, self.df[column])
    print '{failed} cells failed to be parsed to json in {column} (out of {rows})'.format(
        failed=self.json_load_fail_counter, column=column,
        rows=len(self.df))

def loadJson(self, value):
    if not value:
        return value

    # the json dump is not in a python structure
    null, true, false = None, True, False
    value = self.fix_dumped_json(value)
    try:
        if type(value) == dict:
            return value
        else:
            return json.loads(value) if value else {}
    except Exception as e:
        self.json_load_fail_counter += 1
    return {}

@staticmethod
def fix_dumped_json(value):
    value = value.replace('"None"', 'null')
    counter = 0
    for i in value:
        counter += 1 if i == '{' else -1 if i == '}' else 0
    if counter > 0:
        for c in range(counter):
            value += '}'
    return value
```